# Node.js Dependencies as Singletons

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to create my own npm package `my-package` that relies on a dependency `dependency-a` and is used in some project `cool-project` that relies on both `my-package` and `dependency-a`.

```
cool-project
- dependency-a
- my-package
  - dependency-a
```

dependency-a:

```js
export const someVar = 0;
```

my-package:

```
import depA from 'dependency-a'

const someFun = () => {
  depA.someVar = 1;
}
```

cool-project:

```
import depA from 'dependency-a';
import myPackage from 'my-package';

myPackage.someFun();
console.log(depA.someVar); // expected (desired) 1, actual 0
```

The above would work if `myPackage` was a module apart of `cool-project`, however since I want `my-package` to be a standalone npm module, when I try to link it in `cool-project` it seems to be relying on a separate version of `dependency-a`.

Is there a way to create an npm module that can modify a singleton of a third party library, and share that across two modules relying on it automagically. I am using babel/webpack to build `my-package` so if there is a way to do it through that, then that works for me too!

Side note: I know that I could do something like return `depA` from `my-package`--this is not workable for what I need to do. I'm trying to use a version of this example to create a connection middleware for a database.

Answer (score 1):

Add `dependency-a` as a peer dependency in `my-package`'s `package.json` file,

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "dependency-a": "1.x"
  }
```

Now, when installing `my-package`, dependency-a won't be installed automatically if there is another dependency-a (with same version you declared) installed in `cool-project`.

Comment: I'm trying this and having some trouble still. I changed my package.json for my-package per your recommendation above (setting version to * for testing purposes) and reinstalled dependencies. I added `dependency-a` to my webpack externals, as `my-package` cannot build without. Then I linked in `cool-project` and reinstalled dependencies for good measure. `my-package` now throws an error when called through `cool-project` that the module `dependency-a` does not exist. Any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: Did `dependency-a` also exists in package.json of `cool-project`? Or did you only add it through webpack externals?

Comment: Yea I have it as a standard dependency in cool-project. 

Hmm it could be something subtle in my webpack/Babel config. I don’t expect you to debug my code, but if you’re curious the “my-package” in question is here https://github.com/baileytincher/middy-mongoose-connector